# Am I doing wrong with history.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, back, history.js

My web application is using ajax for partial page updating when user goes through pages and links look like

```
...
http://localhost:8080/webapp/#2
http://localhost:8080/webapp/#3
http://localhost:8080/webapp/#4
http://localhost:8080/webapp/#5
...
```

When user goes from ajax page to non-ajax page like from
 `http://localhost:8080/webapp/#4`
to
`http://localhost:8080/webapp/help.html`
then it is required to get the user ability to go back to the previous page by browser back button so to make it work I use `history.js` in the function which controls hash changes

```
$( function() {     
    var History = window.History;
    console.log( "************" + History.enabled );
    $(window).on('hashchange', refreshByHash);
});
```

The problem is when user click `browser back button` from page `help.html` then, at first, the page `webapp/#1` appears for the moment and after that `webapp/#4` appears and it looks like unwanted flickering in the browser.

So what am I doing wrong with `history.js` and how to use it properly to avoid those unwanted flickering.